# How to build a complex table like image under bottom?

Tags: html, html-table, datatables

I have to make a complex and painful painting to put in place then that I take receive a collection of data with which I generate the table

I have under Laravel a data collection that I have to present as the attached image. Please help me build a picture similar to the picture:

[image: Complex table model]

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is a complex header. Look here, hoping it helps.

```
<table id="example" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2"> </th>
            <th colspan="2">Maths</th>
            <th colspan="3">French</th>
          <th colspan="2">Sport</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Ex1</th>
            <th>Ex2</th>
            <th>Ex1</th>
            <th>Ex2</th>
            <th>Ex3</th>
            <th>Ex1</th>
            <th>Ex2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Johnson</td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Franck</td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
```